# How to use thenets/parsoid from Docker in Windows 10 to convert a local text file to html?

Tags: docker, parsoid

I've installed [thenets/parsoid](https://hub.docker.com/r/thenets/parsoid) on Docker on Windows 10. I want to convert the text `pomme.txt` with directory path `F:\zim\pomme.txt` to html. I tried

```
docker run --name myparsoid -d -t -i -v /f/zim:/zim thenets/parsoid:latest sh
type /zim/pomme.txt | docker exec myparsoid node bin/parse.js --wt2html --offline
```

but it returns an error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Akira>docker run --name myparsoid -d -t -i -v /f/zim:/zim thenets/parsoid:latest sh
7912b0cef8fba4244b2519f4f9603ec8e278b67bcc4fe08f4658721b98f941f3

C:\Users\Akira>type /zim/pomme.txt | docker exec myparsoid node bin/parse.js --wt2html --offline
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/bin/parse.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

It's very unclear to me which command to use to convert a local text file to html. Could you please elaborate on how to fix this issue?

Comment: In the example text you try to run `php`, but your error text is trying to run `node`.  The documentation you link to also shows a `php` command.  Can you double-check the command you're running?

Comment: @DavidMaze I sent an email to the author who said that my Parsoid version is old and that I should try `node bin/parse.js`. If I run `type /zim/pomme.txt | docker exec myparsoid php bin/parse.php --wt2html --offline`, then it returns an error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "php": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`.

Comment: It's very unclear to me which command to use to convert a local text file to html.